# Intraweb: Launch an external exe

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I am starting to migrate my VCL application to Intraweb. I'm not used to working with it.
In my VCL code, I am running an external application with "ShellExecute". In Intraweb, I don't know how to do this.

```
ShellExecute(0 , 'OPEN' ,PChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ '.\Application.exe'), Nil, Nil, SW_SHOW);
```

The .exe is located in the "wwwroot".
Do you have any idea how to launch an .exe from my application?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question: if both executables reside in the same folder your code should still work, unbound to how that folder is named.

Comment: In general a web application runs inside a browser and sandboxed, so it won't be able to do many simple tasks of a desktop application. Therefore, in many cases (like this) the answer is not how-to but simply impossible.

Comment: @ Lex Li: No, I don't want the app to run in the web browser. I only want to launch an application from a click of a browser button. For example, we launch a Notepad.

Comment: Intraweb has multiple deployment options but you don't mention which you are using.